# Javascript waiting result of modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a simple question about javascript and bootstrap modal. I have a wizard where I use file upload form, so I check the name of the file and if it doesn't contains some string I have to show a modal where ask if you want to continue anyway. How can I know which button is clicked into modal from javascript or jquery?
I have this code:

```
if (index==3){
    var fileControl = document.getElementById('file');
    //Check if the datatable name contains idFLeet and IdCar. REturn -1 if it not contains the string
    if (fileControl.files[0].name.indexOf($("#selectedFleet").val()) > -1 && fileControl.files[0].name.indexOf($("#selectedCar").val()) > -1){
        //File contains id so you can continue the upload
        uploadFunction();
    }
    else{
        $('#warningDatatableModal').modal("show");  
         //If click on Yes call uploadFunction
        //If click on No return false
    }
}
```

HTML modal code:

```
<div class="modal" id="warningDatatableModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal modal-warning">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Warning</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>There is a incongruity between file name and fleet and
                        car previously selected. Are you sure to continue?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="close" type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="continueButton" type="button" class="btn btn-outline">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
</div>
```

After Yeldar Kurmangaliyev advice I have update my code but the wizard go ahed to the next tab instead of waiting into actual tab

```
if (index==3){
    var fileControl = document.getElementById('file');
    //Check if the datatable name contains idFLeet and IdCar. REturn -1 if it not contains the string
    if (fileControl.files[0].name.indexOf($("#selectedFleet").val()) > -1 && fileControl.files[0].name.indexOf($("#selectedCar").val()) > -1){
        //File contains id so you can continue the upload
        uploadFunction();
    }
    else{
        $('#warningDatatableModal').modal("show");  
        $(".modal-footer > button").click(function() {
            clicked = $(this).text();
            $("#warningDatatableModal").modal('hide');
        });
        $("#warningDatatableModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
            if (clicked === "Cancel"){
                return false;
            }else {
                uploadFunction();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If I put this code out of wizard works(it doesn't close modal with cancel button because I use return false that needs for my wizard), but I need to stop wizard waiting modal result.

Comment: show us the modal code

Comment: you got your HTML, right? So there is two buttons by default, the one is for "Cancel" with (data-target="close" (something like this, don't remember the exact attribute)) which is for closing the modal, and the second one is "Ok" without any bindings on it, you can nest whatever action you want on that buttons, just by using default selectors. `$('.modal-footer button#submit').click(function(){ alert(1); });`

Comment: I added HTML code, with '$('.modal-footer button#submit').click(function(){ alert(1); });' I don't stop javascript execution while the user click on the button

Comment: Added a solution for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply attach events to your buttons.
However, the user may want to close the window without action. The design of modal UI and its overlay suggests to click outside the window and close it.

In order to create an event which will fire event **always** when a user closes your modal, you need to attach to `hide.bs.modal` event:

```
$('#warningDatatableModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
});
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ge5wf9zs/1/).

Comment: I have used your code as my first post but wizard go to the next tab and then it waits for the modal input, but I think that is not possible to stop javascript code like java

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the ids of the buttons and attaching a listener to see when they have been clicked like so:

```
$('#close').on('click',function(){
    //do something
});

$('#continueButton').on('click',function(){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: with this solution the code go ahed, I need modal result to decide if go ahead or stop the wizard